# Cannot login automatically after installing Nvidia drivers on 17.10

Tags: nvidia, gnome, login, startup

As stated, automatic login does not work after installing the  nvidia-384 drivers, even after re-enabling it via the accounts settings.

Comment: Wayland or Xorg ? Is the nvidia driver working with wayland ?

Comment: @panther -- I'm pretty sure the nVidia drivers are not working on wayland yet.

Comment: @panther According to the login session, it's Xorg.